# Generating permutations with CUDA

Tags: c, arrays, cuda

I was reading about CUDA, and I tried to implement a simple code to create every possible permutation of the `array {a,b,c,d}`, but I don't know how to implement the CUDA way (since all the examples I read were of the form `a[blockIdx.x] = b[blockIdx.x] + c[blockIdx.x]` ).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you had installed cuda sdk. It has various examples in samples directory. Try to study and implement, if you face any problem you can ask here with the full reproducer of the problem.

Comment: I use ubuntu, when I CUDA it doesn't created any folder

Comment: By default the path is `/usr/local/cuda/`. You can find the `samples` in `/usr/local/cuda/samples`

Comment: As an alternative to (or in addition to) what suggested by Sagar Masuri, you may wish to take a look at the [CUDA By Example](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/cuda-example-introduction-general-purpose-gpu-programming-0) book which will smoothly introduce you to the topic of parallel programming on GPUs.

Comment: It sounds like you want to enumerate all [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of n=4 things taken k=4 at a time (for which there are `n!/(n-k)!` i.e. 24 unique results in this case) Is that correct?  Or something else?  Perhaps you might sketch a brief outline of the results you are expecting.  Something like the code I describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456042/parallelize-function-which-will-count-all-vectors-with-sum-equal-of-vector-eleme/19462769#19462769) may be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a somewhat naive implementation of a parallel permutation generator in CUDA. The example aims at generating all possible permutations of `ABCD`.

Since all possible permutations can be generated by fixing the first symbol to, say, `X` and appending all possible permutations of the remaining symbols, then changing the first symbol to, say, `Y` and doing the above process again, the simple idea behind the code is to appoint `4` threads to do the job, each thread referring to a different initial symbol.

The permutations following the first symbol are evaluated the canonical way, namely by recursion.

Obviously, the code below can be made more general and perhaps improved, but it should give you a first rough idea to work on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline void GPUassert(cudaError_t code, char * file, int line, bool Abort=true)
{
    if (code != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),file,line);
        if (Abort) exit(code);
    }       
}

#define GPUerrchk(ans) { GPUassert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

__host__ __device__ void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

__device__ void permute_device(char *a, int i, int n, int tid, int* count) 
{
    if (i == n) { 
        char b[4]; char* c = a - 1; 
        b[0] = c[0]; b[1] = c[1]; b[2] = c[2]; b[3] = c[3];
        printf("Permutation nr. %i from thread nr. %i is equal to %s\n", count[0], tid, c); count[0] = count[0] + 1; 
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = i; j <= n; j++)
        {
            swap((a+i), (a+j));
            permute_device(a, i+1, n, tid, count);
            swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
        }
    }
} 

__global__ void permute_kernel(char* d_A, int size) {

    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int count[1]; count[0] = 0;

    char local_array[4];

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) local_array[i] = d_A[i];

    swap(local_array+threadIdx.x,local_array);
    permute_device(local_array+1,0,2,tid,count);

}

int main()
{
    char h_a[] = "ABCD";

    char* d_a; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a,sizeof(h_a));
    GPUerrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, sizeof(h_a), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    printf("\n\n Permutations on GPU\n");
    permute_kernel<<<1,4>>>(d_a, 4);
    GPUerrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    GPUerrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Running only 4 threads on the GPU doesn't make much sense (it will be much slower than running on the CPU). As the number of permutations is `n!`, it's not possible to calculate the number of permutations for an array that is large enough that the number of threads would saturate the GPU. At 16 symbols (only half a warp of threads), you're already at 20 trillion permutations.

Comment: I think you will need to look at implementing an [unranking](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~ruskey/Publications/RankPerm/RankPerm.html) function for permutations. An unranking function for permutations takes an integer (which will be the thread index for CUDA) and translates it to a unique permutation. Because the unranking function is expensive, you will probably want to look into combining it with an iterative approach. So you divide the search space into enough sections that using one thread per section saturates the GPU. Then you start each thread with unranking to set up the initial state.

Answer (score -2):

I wonder if your combination is pairwise.

1. Think about the length of array.(n)
2. Think about the combination complex. (n^2, pairwise)
3. choose a method to calculate in parallel way. (use block id as add offset, and thread id as base one. array(threadid) + array(threadid+offset) for example)

so your kernel should writen like this:

```
template<typename T>
__global__ void 
combination(T* in, T* out) {
  int tid = threadId.x;
  int bid = blockId.x+1;
  out[tid+bid*blockDim.x] = in[tid]+in[(tid+bid)%arrlen];     //0+1, 1+2,..., 0+2, 1+3
}
```

you can call the kernel with `gridDim(arrlen)` and `blockDim(arrlen)`.

Comment: sorry for my careless.

Comment: there are n! permutations of an array not n^2. this isn't correct

Comment: well, I have defined combination as pairwise combine at first line of my answer. For permutation question [Use CUDA to compute all possible combinations of words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284835/use-cuda-to-compute-all-possible-combinations-of-words) and lots answer can be found.

Comment: Your kernel returns the sum of the ordinal values, not the permutations/combinations.  There would be no way to infer what the permutations or combinations were based on the results returned by that kernel.  This is true whether we are speaking pairwise or not.