# Combinations of integers in OpenCL

Tags: algorithm, opencl

I have a bunch of vectors (~500). I need to find triple products of all the combinations of the vectors in OpenCL. There are plenty of [combination algorithms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4675/Combinations-in-C) (r out of n things) in C++ but I am yet to find any implemented for GPU. I have seen quite a few [parallel permutation algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945347/generating-permutations-with-cuda?lq=1) in Cuda but I just want to know if there are any viable combination algorithms present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll need to guess a bit here and there to answer your question.

I suppose you have an array V of n (~500) vectors. These vectors are all of same dimensionality m (probably m=3).

What you want is the component wise product of each 3 vectors v<sub>i</sub>, v<sub>j</sub>, v<sub>k</sub> where i,j,k in {0,..,n-1}.

Simple 3-dimensional example:

```
result[idx].x = V[i].x * V[j].x * V[k].x;
result[idx].y = V[i].y * V[j].y * V[k].y;
result[idx].z = V[i].z * V[j].z * V[k].z;
```

Now maybe your vectors are not 3-dimensional and maybe you don't want the component wise product but the sum of it (like in dot product), but I'm sure you're able to djust the code accordingly.

The real question here is how to compute all possible i,j,k and idx. Correct?

Now with CUDA you are in a very fortunate position. You can just launch n*n*n threads in a grid and therefore get i,j,k for free without having to think about ways to compute combinations or permutations at all. Just do the following:

```
dim3 grid, block;
block.x = n;
block.y = 1;
block z = 1;
grid.x = n;
grid.y = n;
grid.z = 1;

compute_product_kernel<<<grid, block>>>( V, result );
```

This way you'll launch n*n blocks of n threads. Computing i,j,k becomes trivial, computing idx is easy:

```
__device__ void compute_product_kernel( myVector* V, myVector* result)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdx.y;
    int k = threadIdx.x;
    int idx = i * gridDim.y * blockDim.x + j * blockDim.x + k;
    ...
}
```

Of course all of this only works because your n is within the limits of CUDA's block and grid range.

Two more things though:

1. Maybe you want permutations instead of combinations. You could do that by skipping every combination where any two of i,j,k are the same. But I'd recommend keeping them anyway because computing when to skip is probably more expensive that doing the actual work. Also I'd advise against using the permutation to save memory for `result` because it would save you less that 1% and make the calculation much more complex.
2. Are you sure you've got enough memory to actually do this? Storing the result requires n*n*n*m*sizeof(float) bytes. With n=500 and m=3 that would already be 1.5 GB. Is that really what you are looking for? Maybe the next step of your processing can be combined into the calculation so that storing the intermediate result is not neccessary.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Actually the scalar triple product calculates the a.(bxc) for three vectors a,b,c. But I get the general idea that you are presenting. The next step is sorting all the triple products in descending order. So I am not sure I can somehow shorten the step somehow. I should be able to use a subset of the vector set constraining to around 100-200 vectors to decrease the burden.